Is it possible to count element in list with AutoMapper?
I'm using AutoMapper and I'm wondering if it's possible to count elements in a list. I have List elements and the AutoMapper handle maps each element of that list from the source to the Dest object, but my Dest object also has a Number property that is the same as the index in the list + 1. I handled it this way:
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    private int _count = 0;
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest, context) =>
            {
                int number = Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
                dest.Name = "Number" + (number).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
            })
            // some ForMembers ...;
    }
}

but _count is incrementing continuosuly and I am wondering is it possible to reset it to 0 if every elements in list mapped or should I map this property in another place where I get data?

Profiles are singletons and are not meant to keep state. One way to do it is to combine Select with index with Map. Or you could also use AM's context, but that seems excessive.
